# Serializing a generic binary search tree with a bunch of child objects, including a binary tree

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, binary-search-tree

I've got a very complex binary search tree. It's node data should keep an object of custom KeyValue class. As a key there should be a string, and value is another tree, which data field contains an object of custom KeyValue class, where key is a string and value is string[].

I need to serialize and deserialize it, using XML serializer.

The problem is that serialization isn't done properly. XML file does not contain Nodes as elements, only their data.

Therefore, it can't be deserialized, a new tree's root is null.
Here is how I perform serialization.

```
            XmlSerializer XMLserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RecursiveKeyValueTree<string, RecursiveKeyValueTree<string, string[]>>), extraTypes);
        XmlSerializerNamespaces myNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        myNamespace.Add("", "");

        using (FileStream serializationStream = File.Create("dictionaryTreeExample.xml"))
            XMLserializer.Serialize(serializationStream, dictionaryTree, myNamespace);

        RecursiveKeyValueTree<string, RecursiveKeyValueTree<string, string[]>> dictionaryTreeDeserialized;

        using (FileStream deserializationStream = File.OpenRead("dictionaryTreeExample.xml"))
        {

            dictionaryTreeDeserialized = (RecursiveKeyValueTree<string, RecursiveKeyValueTree<string, string[]>>)XMLserializer.Deserialize(deserializationStream);
        }
```

XML file:

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the object graph that you use to represent the binary tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Add() method in the binary tree had an unnecessary check before inserting elements, thus, it prevented elements of the outer tree from being inserted.